# New-PSDrive doesn't work when script is run from network share, but does work when run on the local machine

Tags: powershell, try-catch

Context: IT staff may or may not log in with a local administrator account and run the following script. Due to the way Windows credential caching works on a local admin account, a simple copy and paste of the files without hardcoded credentials from a UNC path may not work occasionally.

My workaround for this issue was to just create a PSDrive for the session using a set of credentials that are reserved exclusively for scripting and domain joins.

IT staff access this script from the same server (fileserver05). The script attempts to make a temporary map of fileserver05. Is it just looping and confusing itself, or what?

```
Function Install {
    Start-Process net -wait -ArgumentList "use X /delete" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-PSDrive X -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    Try {
        $agentPass = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Deployment operations supervisor password"
            $agentUser = 'domain.com\agent'
            $agentCred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $agentUser,$agentPass

        New-PSDrive -Name "X" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\fileserver05\Fileserver05\IT\Programs\Windows\Yardi CHECKscan Client" -Credential $agentCred -ErrorAction Stop

        Write-Host 'Deploying CHECKscan client to local machine...'
            Copy-Item -Path "X:\install.msi" -Destination "${env:TEMP}" -Force
            Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList "/i `"${env:TEMP}\install.msi`" /qn /norestart"
        Write-Host 'Deploying connection settings to current and default user profile...'
            Copy-Item -Path "X:\yCheckSettings.xml" -Destination "${env:APPDATA}" -Force
            Copy-Item -Path "X:\yCheckSettings.xml" -Destination "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming" -Force
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "An error occured during installation" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White
        Write-Host "Ensure you have the correct credentials and a connection to the corporate network"
        Write-Host "Ensure that paths to the installation files have not changed on the fileserver"
        Write-Host ""
        Install
    }
}

Install
```

Please also note that ExecutionPolicy is set to Unrestricted.

If a staff member runs the script from the server, it fails and is unable to map the drive, therefore making the rest of the script not work. If a staff member takes the script and drags it to the local desktop, then runs it, it succeeds.

How can I make it so it can be ran from the server itself?

Comment: What is the error it gives when it fails ? please update the question with the error.

Comment: Add Write-Host $_ to your Catch block to see the error